# Saving a radial gradient for web (photoshop)

Tags: photoshop, radial-gradients, image-optimization

I have a .psd document that consists of a radial background that I'd like to use for the web (the starting and end colors are 2 shades of gray). I tried saving this background for the web in different formats: gif, jpg (100% quality) and png. However, the results all look bad, there is no smooth transition between colors and I can clearly see the different circles.

Is there a way for me to save it for the web in a manner that it looks similar to the original high quality .psd?

Comment: I'm now suspecting the problem could be coming from my monitor. I tried on a different one and the circles (bands) are not as noticeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jpeg is the best file format for a nice smooth gradient transition and smallest file size; assuming you don't need transparency.

And it does sound like it may simply be your monitor sucks.